# How to pass array value from view to another view Laravel 5.7

Tags: arrays, laravel, parameters

I want to get the value from the array I've passed from the first view to another view.
I found this works by using route (not url), but I don't know how to get it without parameter in the controller.
Please help me within the right syntax.

This is the latest code I've tried

```
$id = $request->id;
if($request->has('download', 'id')){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');
        return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf',['id'=>$id])->with('id',$id);}
```

This is my code *used to download pdf file from a view

Controller

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $items = DB::table("items")->get();
    view()->share('items',$items);
    $id = $request->only(['id']);

    if($request->has('download', 'id')){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');
        return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf', ['id'=>$id])->with('id', $id);
    }


    return view('pdfview', ['id'=>$id])->with('id', $id);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('pdfview',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'MaatwebsiteDemoController@pdfview'));
```

View

```
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf','id' => $employee->nip]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

---

I want to get the `$employee->nip` value

But it is still **Undefined variable: id**

Comment: where did you fetch `$employee` and how did you pass it to your view? please provide some of your view code and the method that returned the view.

Comment: @foreach($employees as $employee)
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf','id' => $employee->nip]) }}">Download PDF</a>
@endforeach

this code works, i can see the right data by hovering the link i want to click

Comment: so what is the problem? who throws undefined variable: id

Answer (score 1):

Don't really have time to test it. But this thread looks promising.

https://laravel.io/forum/03-14-2016-basics-passing-info-from-one-view-to-another